# Integrating iOS 6 Twitter and Facebook share feature with responsive website

Tags: ios6, responsive-design, social-media

I'm working on a responsive website. Currently when a user clicks the "Tweet" or "Like" button it takes the user to another page to complete the steps. I wonder whether there is a way we can integrate iOS 6's inbuilt Twitter and Facebook functionality rather than directing to the user to another separate page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At this time of this writing, there is no way to access the Share Widget available on iOS6.

Source: [A search on Apple Developer Search](https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=share%20widget)